# How do I make a NEXT version 13 application with Electron?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, electron

I have a project in NEXT, more precisely in version 13.0.4, and this project will be a game for windows.

- How can I add Electron in a NEXT project, in this new version that has file routing and many other benefits?
- How to configure *Electron+Next* 13 stack to compile? Why can't I find an `index.html` that I can pass to my Electron to open a window

Yes, I know the libraries: [nextron](https://github.com/saltyshiomix/nextron) and [electron-next](https://github.com/leo/electron-next) , but none of them use next13 and I need the file routing functionality

Can anyone help me with this?

- Electron configuration in a next project
- Build configuration for this project

Thank you very much! I really need this help

[github of my project in next13](https://github.com/Lucas-B-C-Oliveira/baccarat-v2)

I tried to build the project, but since I don't know which file to point to in my electron, it turned out that I can't open a window with electron

Comment: You've linked Nextron. Checking their GitHub page makes it seem that Next.js 13 support is planned for v9 of that project. Also, there are issues mentioning Next.js 13 there (some people already working with it, it seems), so it might be a good idea to ask there (if there's no documentation available for that usecase). Furthermore, for the next time, please refrain from linking entire Git repositories but instead share a [mcve] so your problem is reproducible from here directly.